# how to create docker restricted network

Tags: docker, docker-network

I'm trying to run a docker container in a restricted network environment (one port open to the internet). I read that I could add some iptables rules on the host system, but I don't want to affect other containers. So I created another bridge 'docker1' to put the iptables rules on it. But I cannot use it as a bridge in docker:

```
# docker network create -d bridge -b docker1 restricted
unknown shorthand flag: 'b' in -b
See 'docker network create --help'.
```

I tried --bridge, changing places and stuff, nothing works, but I saw this use in the internet. What am I doing wrong and how I could get around it? How can I create a network with only one port NATed to the internet for only a group of containers, not all of them?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define the network as a bridge unless you are in an old swarm environment, bridge is the default for a single node docker host. And there's no need to pass a bridge name, just let Docker workout the name on the backend. Your command is simply:

```
docker network create restricted
```

Comment: But how do I restrict this network? Say I don't want any traffic to come out of it except for one port. That's the main point.

Comment: That's not done by the default bridge network. You'd need to modify the iptables rules on the Docker host to support that, unless someone has created a custom network plugin.

Comment: That's what I was aiming at in the first place. I guess I'll have to take a closer look at the docker chains, so that only one network would be restricted. Thanks.